# How to remove double quotes from string in json using regexp in ksqldb

Tags: json, regex, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I know many questions were posted on similar issue but couldnt solve my usecase.

I have following invalid json which is having double quotes in string and trying to remove double quotes inside string using ksql query with regular expression. But this regexp is not giving valid json. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**INPUT String contains double quotes :**

"values":[["Diese Zimmer werden im Vergleich zu den ***"normalen"*** Zimmern im Hotel über zusätzliche oder verbesserte Einrichtungen im Badezimmer verfügen, wie zB ein separates Bidet, Waschbecken für sie und ihn oder Regenbrause."]]},

**INPUT JSON:**

```
{"id":"f92ebba3-fff8-48b8","of":null,"domain":"quality-type","rootState":"NONE","sources":[{"code":"GT04_CT04-DOD","description":[{"values":[["These rooms will feature additional or enhanced facilities in the bathroom compared to 'standard' rooms in the hotel such as a separate bidet, his & hers wash basins, or rainfall shower head."]]},{"conditions":[{"value":"de","type":"language"}],"values":[["Diese Zimmer werden im Vergleich zu den "normalen" Zimmern im Hotel über zusätzliche oder verbesserte Einrichtungen im Badezimmer verfügen, wie zB ein separates Bidet, Waschbecken für sie und ihn oder Regenbrause."]]},{"conditions":[{"value":"en","type":"language"}],"values":[["These rooms will feature additional or enhanced facilities in the bathroom compared to 'standard' rooms in the hotel such as a separate bidet, his & hers wash basins, or rainfall shower head."]]}],"domain":"upgrade-type","inactive":[{"values":[[false]]}],"name":[{"conditions":[{"value":"de","type":"language"}],"values":[["Badezimmerausstattung"]]},{"conditions":[{"value":"en","type":"language"}],"values":[["Bathroom Facilities"]]},{"values":[["Bathroom Facilities"]]}],"schemaVersion":"v1","source":"bod","version":"2021-02-22T16:16:06.768741Z"}],"hasGr":true}
```

**Regular Expression used**:
**`([^:,{])"([^:,}])`**

**Ksql query:**

```
select  regexp_replace(MESSAGEVALUE,'([^:,{])"([^:,}])','') as Messagevalue from dev_quality_test;
```

**Output String :**

```
"values":[iese Räume werden im Wohn- oder Schlafbereich im Vergleich zu den tandardZimmern des Hotels über zusätzliche oder verbe|
```

|sserte Einrichtungen verfügen, wie beispielsweise einen Deckenventilator, ein rundes Bett oder eine Pod-Kaffeemaschine]}

**Expected String:**

```
"values":[["Diese Zimmer werden im Vergleich zu den ***normalen*** Zimmern im Hotel über zusätzliche oder verbesserte Einrichtungen im Badezimmer verfügen, wie zB ein separates Bidet, Waschbecken für sie und ihn oder Regenbrause."]]},
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Valid JSON
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. You've got a valid JSON input string, but you want to parse it with regex? Perhaps you can edit your question to include your expected output? And also why you haven't just declared the schema of the JSON in the `CREATE STREAM` statement instead?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have updated my question with expected output.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're attempting to do. You've got a valid JSON input, why you haven't just declared the schema of the JSON in the CREATE STREAM statement instead?

Comment: if your flavor of regex supports negative lookaheads and negative lookbehinds you may use (?<!{|:|,|\\[)\"(?!}|:|,|\\])